# When are socket buffers deemed ready for reading/writing?

Tags: python, sockets

I have two pieces of code, a server and a client for a chat application using python 'socket' and 'selectors' modules. The 'service_connection' function should only do something when a socket is ready for reading. However as far as i'm aware, all the client does is send a message containing the client's username. This is dealt with in 'accept_connection' function. However I then receive an error resulting from the 'service_connection' function. Why is my program getting to this point?

Client:

```
import socket
import selectors

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 54321

username = input('Enter username: ')

# Set up client socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
sock.setblocking(False)

# Send username to server with a header
username_enc = username.encode("utf-8")
user_header = f'{len(username_enc):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}'.encode("utf-8")
sock.send(user_header + username_enc)
```

Server:

```
import socket
import selectors

HEADER_LENGTH = 10
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 54321
clients = []  # List for storing client information


def accept_connection(sock):
    """Function to accept a new connection"""

    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print(f'Connected to by {addr}')
    conn.setblocking(False)

    # Receive first message. This will contain username
    user_header = conn.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
    username_length = int(user_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
    username = conn.recv(username_length).decode("utf-8")

    # Register socket with sel 
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    data = {"addr": addr, "username": username, "socket": conn}
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)
    clients.append(data)


def service_connection(key, mask):
    """Function to service an existing connection"""

    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    # Check for read events
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        # Receive message from socket
        msg_header = sock.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
        if msg_header is None:
            print(f'Closing connection to {data.addr}')
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
            clients = [client for client in clients if client.addr!=data.addr]
            return None
        msg_length = int(msg_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
        msg = sock.recv(msg_length).decode("utf-8")

        # Create username header
        username_enc = data.username.encode("utf-8")
        user_header = f'{len(username_enc):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}'.encode("utf-8")

        # Distribute message to all other connected clients
        for client in clients:
            if client.addr == data.addr:
                continue
            client.socket.send(user_header + msg_header + msg.encode())


# Set up listening socket
lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
lsock.bind((HOST, PORT))
lsock.listen()
lsock.setblocking(False)

# Set up selectors object
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

# Loop over blocking calls to select
while True:
    events = sel.select()
    for key, mask in events:
        if key.data is None:
            # Listening socket is ready. Accept new connection
            accept_connection(key.fileobj)
        else:
            # Existing socket is ready. Service it
            service_connection(key, mask)
```

Both server and client run as expected. However once I provide a username in the client script, I receive the following output server-side:

```
Connected to by ('127.0.0.1', 62636)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 78, in <module>
    service_connection(key, mask)
  File "server.py", line 44, in service_connection
    msg_length = int(msg_header.decode("utf-8").strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Try to print "msg_header" after "msg_header = sock.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)" and post it

Comment: The lengths of chunks you `.recv()` from a streaming protocol like TCP have *no connection whatsoever* to the lengths of chunks that were sent.  You get however many bytes have made it to the network buffers on your machine at that moment in time - including the possibility of zero bytes, if you've set the socket to non-blocking mode.

Comment: @Wonka - So the msg_header gets printed as b' '. So I don't understand why sel.select() is returning a socket thats ready for reading

Comment: No, the message header does not print as `b''`,  the argument to `int` is `''`. That means that `msg_header` contained only white space which you then `strip()`ed and supplied to `int`. For the reasons @jasonharper mentioned this code wouldn't make sense with blocking sockets, with non-blocking it only gets further away from functional.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Sorry I don't understand, I tested it and that is what `msg_header` prints. It is an empty byte string. This is because when the client script is finished it sends 0 bytes to the server and closes the socket connection. I believe this is the answer to my question. The error in my code (or at least the one relevant to my question!) is that `if msg_header is None:` should be `if not msg_header:`. Could you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your answer, but could you please explain further. Whilst using sockets I have always done something like send(10 bytes) on the client side and recv(10 bytes) on the server side and this has always worked without fail. Could you please explain what you mean when you say there's no connection between the length of chunks sent and length of chunks received? Have I just been getting lucky? Thanks!

Comment: You've just been getting lucky.  You might only receive one byte at a time, you might receive multiple full messages at a time, or anything in between.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the client script is finished it sends 0 bytes to the server and closes the socket connection. The server-side socket therefore has 0 bytes ready for reading. For `service_connection()` to work properly the line `if msg_header is None:` needs to be changed to `if not msg_header:`